# Keep format of java eclipse code in LYX

Tags: eclipse, lyx

Is there any software I could use in **Eclipse** where I can transfer the format of my code just as it is into **Lyx** ? I am using Java and the default format in **Lyx** is not as I expected and it says the code is too long so it throws exception in **Lyx**.

Comment: You could try formatting the Java code in Eclipse before trying to edit it in Lyx.  Eclipse formatting will break up long lines.

Comment: I already set up the format in Properties -> Java Code Style -> Formatter to short lines.... but I guess Lyx has problems if the classes extends a certain size... the prinatble page doesn't show everything....

Comment: Lyx is a document processor.  I think you'd be better off using Eclipse or Netbeans.